How to check my current installed Skia version in Delphi?
I am having some skia issues and I think I might have an old version installed. Global Skia is enabled in my project, but how can I see what version of Skia is installed and used?
How can I check my current installed Skia version in Delphi?

Delphi 12 and newer:
You can check for the SkVersion constant variable in the System.Skia unit.
const
  SkVersion = '6.1.0';

Older than Delphi 12
You can also check for the SkVersion constant variable, but the unit name might be different depending on the Skia version, regardless, the unit name will always contain Skia.pas in it. So look in the Skia.pas unit for SkVersion

If you have the source code, you can check it in skia/RELEASE_NOTES.txt, the document records the all milestone release info.
